# find or list methods inside particular method of current executing page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

There is an asp.net webpage. Inside `Page_Load` event there could be multiple method calls (`MethodA`, `MethodB(arg1, arg2)` etc.)

I have httpmodule. While accessing the page, it will first go thorough httpmodule.

Inside that hpttpmodule, I want to find or list all methods which are being called in current executing page's `Page_Load`.

By this way, I want to make sure that a particular method (`MethodA`) with its signature is implemented inside `Page_Load` event.

I will appreciate any implementation, weather httpmodule, base page, abstract class, interfaces, reflection etc... anything to achieve this objective.

Thanks

Comment: Side note: adding actual goal may help people to add alternative solutions... Your current one essentially limits asnwers to PhaDaPhunk's one (+1) that show how to disassemble method.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this :

```
MethodBase methodBase = typeof(INSERT_CLASS_HERE).GetMethod(INSERT_METHOD_HERE);
var instructions = MethodBodyReader.GetInstructions(methodBase);

foreach (Instruction instruction in instructions)
{
MethodInfo methodInfo = instruction.Operand as MethodInfo;

if(methodInfo != null)
{
    Type type = methodInfo.DeclaringType;
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();

    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}({2});",
        type.FullName,
        methodInfo.Name,
        String.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType.FullName + " " + p.Name).ToArray())
    );
}
```

}

Where `INSERT_CLASS_HERE` is the name of the class where you want to look.
And `INSERT_METHOD_HERE` is the name of the method within the class in which you want to find all calls.